# discord.collection is not a constructor

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to write a discord bot and am constantly getting this error whenever i try to run it.

```
TypeError: discord.collection is not a constructor
```

It's from this line of code

```
bot.commands = new discord.collection();
```

I'm not the best at JavaScript and have looked around google and can't find anything that matches my exact issue, all the ones I find have the same error but are something completely different.
whether or not this command is outdated or no longer in use I am unsure of but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How did you define `discord`

Comment: const discord = require('discord.js');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `Collection`, not `collection`. The standard for naming classes is always first letter capitalized.

Comment: Thank you-_- probably the biggest brain fart I've had in a while.